# split string before ('/') inside PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I have a usecase that I would like to split like below. (CONTOSO)

```
"Name","FullAccess","SendAs"
"Shared11","",""
"Shared21","CONTOSO\usr11,CONTOSO\tst12","contoso.local/Users/John,contoso.local/Users/Maria"
```

After splitting,

```
"Name","FullAccess","SendAs"
"Shared11","",""
"Shared21","usr11,tst12","contoso.local/Users/John,contoso.local/Users/Maria"
```

My script :

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox

# creating a table to combine information
$MailboxesResult = @()

# processing all the mailboxes
ForEach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes){

    $permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
    $fullAccess = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" }
    $permissions = Get-RecipientPermission -Identity $mailbox.Alias | ? { ($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.Trustee -Like "NT AUTHORITY*") }
    $SendAs = $permissions | Where-Object { $permissions.AccessRights -eq "SendAs" }

    # combine eveything in a PSCustomObject
    $item = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name                          = $mailbox.DisplayName
        FullAccess                    = $($fullAccess.User) -join (",")
        SendAs                        = $($sendas.Trustee) -join (",")
    }
    $MailboxesResult += $item
}
```

My output:

```
"Name","FullAccess","SendAs"
"Shared11","",""
"Shared21","CONTOSO\usr11,CONTOSO\tst12","contoso.local/Users/John,contoso.local/Users/Maria"
```

My desired output:

```
"Name","FullAccess","SendAs"
"Shared11","",""
"Shared21","usr11,tst12","contoso.local/Users/John,contoso.local/Users/Maria"
```

UPDATE1:

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>    $fullAccess.User

```
SecurityIdentifier                             ReturnUrlTokenEncodedString   RawIdentity
                                      
    S-1-5-21-609545082-2795152396-2074981628-3348    FALSE                        CONTOSO\usr11
    S-1-5-21-609545082-2795152396-2074981628-16854   FALSE                        CONTOSO\tst12
```

$($fullAccess.User) -join (",")

```
CONTOSO\usr11,CONTOSO\tst12
```

($fullAccess.User | foreach-object { $_.Split("")[1] }) -join ","

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.SecurityPrincipalIdParameter] does not contain a method named 'Split'.
At line:1 char:38
+ ($fullAccess.User | foreach-object { $_.Split("\")[1] }) -join ","
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

UPDATE2:

lets say , $fullAccess variable is empty

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>    $fullAccess

**There is no any error message such as `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`**

[PS] C:\Windows\system32> $($fullAccess.User) -join (",")

**After I am trying your script. actually it works but if variable is empty then I am getting an error message.**

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>($fullAccess.User.RawIdentity | foreach-object { $_.Split("")[1] }) -join ","

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:50
+ ($fullAccess.User.RawIdentity | foreach-object { $_.Split("\")[1] }) -join ","
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Third try lucky (I'll delete the previous two comments to clean up)... ```FullAccess = ($fullAccess.User.RawIdentity | foreach-object { $_.Split("\")[1] }) -join ","```

Comment: `$fullAccess.User -replace '^.+\\' -join ','`